# How do I add this script to make my menu open on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouse

Okay so basically I have this almost done but I wanted to make this menu open on mouse hover.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs().addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
    $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
  });
```

And I wanted this to be mouse hover as it needs to be clicked for now. The script for the hover is

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      event: "mouseover"
    });
  });
```

but everytime I mix or override the old function to this hover, it ruins everything. Thanks guys.

Comment: Please give more information about your code, maybe the `html` structure of your menu and which element is shown on the hover of which element. And this seems to be `jquery-ui` as well.

Comment: I'm doing a jquery code.. This is the one I want but on a vertical mode. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are reinitializing the whole thing, thats why you mess up everything.

Try this instead:

```
$(function() {
   $( "#tabs" ).tabs({event: "mouseover"}).addClass( "ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix" );
   $( "#tabs li" ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-left" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!